# New Tag request: [singularity-scheduler]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-creation-process

[HubSpot/Singularity](https://github.com/HubSpot/Singularity) is a Scheduler (HTTP API and webapp) for running Mesos tasks - long-running processes, one-off tasks, and scheduled jobs.

More: http://getsingularity.com/

Related questions:

1. [Singularity failing to create slave on Rancher with RHEL 7 instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46560097/singularity-failing-to-create-slave-on-rancher-with-rhel-7-instances)
2. [Does singularity support the gpu resources framework capability?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40612044/does-singularity-support-the-gpu-resources-framework-capability)
3. [Mesos Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28458504/mesos-framework)
4. [Apache Mesos Workflows - Event Driven Scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26994490/apache-mesos-workflows-event-driven-scheduler)

Comment: Tags aren't created in isolation. Are there any current questions the tag would apply?

Comment: @yannis Sorry, didn't know that, Yes, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46560097/singularity-failing-to-create-slave-on-rancher-with-rhel-7-instances

Comment: Ok then, anyone with the ["create tags" privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags) should be able to add the tag to the question. I'd add it myself, but I know nothing of the tool and I'm not sure [singularity-scheduler] is the best tag for it.

Comment: A single question of dubious topicality (at least in my eyes) is not enough to warrant the creation of a tag. If there are *other* questions that need this tag, please [edit] the links into your question.

Comment: @yannis yes, we can discuss what would be the correct tag instead of [singularity-scheduler], I just wanted to start the discussion

Comment: @CodyGray I added several related questions I could find.

Comment: I wonder how this is a [duplicate]? If there is another tag request for Singularity, we can move the discussion there.

Comment: @VadimKotov The answer too say "As an alternative, you can request the creation of a tag by starting a new meta discussion. This gives other people the opportunity to discuss if the new tag is needed. "

Comment: I marked it as a duplicate because, originally, you hadn't shown cause for the tag's creation. Since you edited, I've re-opened.